# Traversing a tree in Pre-order

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am new to clojure as well as to Functional Programming. I am trying to traverse a tree in pre-order using:

```
(def preordercoll [])

(deftrace preorder [mytree]
  (if-not (empty? mytree)
    (do (println "position"(value mytree))
        (cons (value mytree) (preorder (left-child mytree)))
        (cons (value mytree) (preorder (right-child mytree))))
      )preordercoll) )

(preorder [45[65 [90 nil nil] [81 nil nil]] [72[82 nil nil][96 nil nil]]])
```

I am unable to append values of node in some list, like I tried using 'conj' operation on global variable `preordercoll`, but yes it doesn't work like object oriented , so I tried using cons, but only few values are returned, that too in improper order. Can anyone guide me what mistake am making?

I also thought of using Partial function but could not find how to supply value of node in recursive manner. Am not asking for code but please draw me in right direction to get collection of values in pre-order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're on the right track, just have the nesting of the `cons` calls a little off. First a note on evaluation of forms in clojure. One of the key ideas is that *every* form evaluates to something* which is why there is no "return" statement in the language, because you could say everything would be a return statement so what's the point in having it. In the case of a `do` expression the return value of the expression is the last statement so:

```
(do 1 2 3)
```

returns (evaluates to) `3`. In the `do` expression in your code it returns the result of the second cons, and the first cons has no effect.

```
(do (println "position"(value mytree))
    (cons (value mytree) (preorder (left-child mytree))) ;; <-- this does nothing
    (cons (value mytree) (preorder (right-child mytree))))
```

instead it sounds like you would like an expression that starts with the result of calling preorder on the left tree, then concatinates the result of calling preorder on the right tree, then attaches the current node's value to the front of that.

```
(let [left-side (preorder (left-child mytree))
      right-side (preorder (left-child mytree))
      this-value (value mytree)]
   (do (println "position" this-value)
       (cons this-value (concat right-side left-side))
```

*(for the pedants) "except the ignore reader maco #_"

Comment: Thank you so much, am so relieved as I was trying since long and was not able to make out my mistake.Thanks for detailed explanation, understood well :)

Comment: there is also a useful library for walking tree like tings built into clojure: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html#clojure.walk/prewalk